# How to turn only member variables into byte array in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof

***TL;DR***

I have a struct with more than just member variables (e.g. they contain functions), and I want to convert only the member variables into a byte array(/vector), such that I can upload data to the graphics card in Vulkan. How do I get only that part of the struct, which represents the member variables?

***My concrete approach***

I have a setup where I use an empty `ParamsBase` struct and from that inherit `ParamsA`, `ParamsB` ... structs which actually contain member variables. I use this such that I can keep members of `ParamsBase` in a `Container` class without actual knowledge of the concrete implementation.

I want to turn the Params instance in the `Container` class into a byte buffer.

Since I need the size of the actual `ParamsA`/`ParamsB`/... struct, I have used a generic subclass for these when creating instances that allows me to [use a single `getSize()` function, rather than overwriting this in every substruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294936/sizeofthis-and-decltypethis-in-derived-classes).

```
// =============================
// === Define Params structs ===
// =============================
struct ParamsBase
{
    virtual size_t getSize() const noexcept = 0;
};

struct ParamsA : public ParamsBase
{
    float vec[3] = { 2.3f, 3.4f, 4.5f };
};

// ===============================================================
// === enable sizeof query for derived structs from ParamsBase ===
// ===============================================================
template<class T>
struct GetSizeImpl : T
{
    using T::T;
    size_t getSize() const noexcept final { return sizeof(T); }
};

template<class T, class... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> create(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new GetSizeImpl<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

// ============
// === Util ===
// ============
template<typename T>
std::vector<uint8_t> asByteVector(T* t, size_t size)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> byteVec;
    byteVec.reserve(size);
    uint8_t* dataArr = std::bit_cast<uint8_t*>(t);
    byteVec.insert(byteVec.end(), &dataArr[0], &dataArr[size]);
    return byteVec;
}

// ============================================
// === Use Params struct in container class ===
// ============================================
class Container
{
public:
    Container(ParamsBase* params) : Params(params) {}

    const std::vector<uint8_t>& getParamsAsBuffer()
    {
        ParamsAsBuffer = asByteVector(Params, Params->getSize());
        return ParamsAsBuffer;
    }

    size_t getParamsSize() const { return Params->getSize(); }

private:
    ParamsBase* Params = nullptr;

    std::vector<uint8_t> ParamsAsBuffer;
};
```

Using all this, the sizes of my Params structs is too large and starts of with two bytes containing some garbage(?) data. I assume it has to do with the `getSize()` function, since even a non-templated struct with a function has this problem, but I cannot be sure if this assumption is correct.

This little comparison shows differences between what I get and what I want:

```
// ================================
// === Define comparison struct ===
// ================================
struct ParamsCompareA
{
    float vec[3] = { 2.3f, 3.4f, 4.5f };
};

int main()
{
    // create instances
    auto pA = create<ParamsA>();
    Container cA(pA.get());
    std::vector<uint8_t> vecA = cA.getParamsAsBuffer();

    // comparison
    ParamsCompareA pcA;

    size_t sizeCompA = sizeof(ParamsCompareA);
    std::vector<uint8_t> compVecA = asByteVector(&pcA, sizeof(ParamsCompareA));

    std::cout << "ParamsA size: " << std::to_string(pA->getSize()) 
        << "; CompParamsA size: " << sizeof(ParamsCompareA) << std::endl;

    float* bufAf = reinterpret_cast<float*>(vecA.data());
    float* bufCompAf = reinterpret_cast<float*>(compVecA.data());
}
```

The `compVecA` contains 12 entries (i.e. the struct is 12 bytes large), reinterpreting them as floats shows the correct values. The `vecA` is reported to have 24 entries and the actual data I want is at (0 based) bytes 2 to 14.

I could hardcode an offset of 2 (which is the same as `sizeof(GetSizeImpl)`), but I'm pretty sure this is not the correct way to handle this. So, is there a way I can get to only the data part I want?

The purpose of the Param sub structs is to make it as easy as possible for a user to add their own Parameter struct and upload it to a Vulkan Buffer (/Shader), i.e. they should worry only about the data they actually need and I can do all the handling and conversion elsewhere.

Comment: Polymorphism and virtual functions are usually implemented using a hidden private member variable, whose size is included in the `sizeof` of the object. If you want to use polymorphism and virtual functions, you can't just do a raw byte-wise copy an object into a byte array. You need to *serialize* the data.

Comment: I only read TL;DR part. If you need to `std::memcpy` your struct, then just make it [POD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) and define methods manipulating is somewhere else: in another struct by composition, or as free functions.

Comment: Just as a side note: Structs only contain the data, function code is always separate. However if there are virtual functions involved there's an additional, hidden v-table pointer (or several ones on more complex inheritance structures).

Comment: @pptaszni Thanks, but I need to get the size and a byte array copy of the struct without knowing its exact type (or I'll have to think of a different system for my problem entirely).

Comment: Oki I see what you might need, but your approach with `truct GetSizeImpl : T` is both overcomplicated and wrong - because it contains vtable.. Just impl virtual `std::vector<uint8_t> Params::serialize();` functions and you are good to go. It can be trivial `memcpy` of members, or something [more sophisticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/is-it-possible-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-class-in-c)

Comment: You are missing calls to `std::start_lifetime_as_array` to allow `bufAf` to be read from.

Comment: @Caleth I only added those arrays for debugging where the actual data would start, they wouldn't be used in the real program. Thanks for the hint though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't derive `ParamsA` from anything. Have a wrapper type that provides the behaviours shared between each param type.

```
struct ParamsA // No inheritance!
{
    float vec[3] = { 2.3f, 3.4f, 4.5f };
};

struct BaseParameters {
    virtual std::span<std::byte> as_bytes() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Parameters : BaseParameters {
    T data;
    /// ... other data members as you need
    std::span<std::byte> as_bytes() {
        return std::span(&data, 1).as_bytes();
    }
};

struct ParamsCompareA
{
    float vec[3] = { 2.3f, 3.4f, 4.5f };
};

int main()
{
    // create instances
    auto * pA = new Parameters<ParamsA>{};
    auto vecA = pA->as_bytes();

    // comparison
    ParamsCompareA pcA;

    std::cout << "ParamsA size: " << std::to_string(vecA.size()) 
        << "; CompParamsA size: " << sizeof(ParamsCompareA) << std::endl;

    float* bufAf = reinterpret_cast<float *>(vecA.data());
    float* bufCompA = pcA.vec;
}
```

Comment: Just a few annotations, since there are some syntax errors. It needs to be ```struct BaseParameters {
    virtual std::span<const std::byte> as_bytes() = 0;
};``` and ```template <typename T>
struct Parameters : BaseParameters {
    T data;
    /// ... other data members as you need
    std::span<const std::byte> as_bytes() {
        return std::as_bytes(std::span(&data, 1));
    }
};```
Works like a charm though, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

By adding a couple of conventions and layouts this is possible to do with your current setup.

The first modification is to declare the member variables inside a struct within the `Param` structs.

```
struct ParamsA : public ParamsBase
{
    struct Members {
        float vec[3] = { 2.3f, 3.4f, 4.5f };
    } m;
};
```

Then add another virtual function to `ParamBase`

```
virtual const void* data() const = 0;
```

Now we can change `GetSizeImpl::getSize` to return `sizeof(T::Members)` instead, and also override the other function

```
const void* data() const override { return &this->T::m; }
```

Now you have both the correct byte size of the data and a pointer to the POD data, which you legally can `memcpy` as much as you want to.

Comment: This worked nicely. I opted for the second answer, since that is a little less overhead for anyone creating their own parameters, but this is till a nice way to do it, thank you.