# Find out the size of a polymorphic object

Tags: c++, polymorphism, sizeof

I have an pointer `Base* base_ptr` to an polymorphic object. Is it possible to find out the size of the dynamic type of said object?

AFAIK, `sizeof(*base_ptr)` yilds the size of the static type of `base_ptr`. I'm beginning to suspect this isn't possible, but maybe I'm overlooking something.

Note: I'm aware that I could add a virtual function to my type hierarchy which returns the size, but this is not a desirable solution in my case.

EDIT: `sizeof(base_ptr)` -> `sizeof(*base_ptr)`

Comment: `sizeof(base_ptr)` gives you the size of the pointer, not of any class.

Comment: It looks like even the g++-specific <cxxabi.h> doesn't provide this information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't do that in C++ - at least in a portable way. The best bet would be to have `getSize()` member function implemented in each class.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. You can implement a virtual function in the base class which returns the size:

```
class Base
{
   virtual int size() { return sizeof(Base); }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
   virtual int size() { return sizeof(Derived); }
};

//......
Base* b = new Derived;
int size = b->size(); //will call Derived::size() and return correct size
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CRTP idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), if possible, as I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14730166/908336